# Paginate on LDAP server which does not support PagedResultsControl

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, spring-ldap, ldap-query

I'm trying to get all entries on an LDAP server using Spring LDAP (version 2.3.2). Within my code, I make use of `PagedResultsDirContextProcessor` to paginate through all the result. This works fine on the servers which support `PagedResultsControl`.

However, I now need to connect to an LDAP server which does not support `PagedResultsControl`. How can I get all entries without using `PagedResultsControl`?

Comment: I have found that I can use Virtual List View - is this something supported in Spring LDAP?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `VirtualListView` via JNDI. You have to retrieve and re-supply the 'contextID' to paginate, as follows:

```
static final int LIST_SIZE = 20; // Adjust to suit

@Test
public void TestVLV() throws NamingException, IOException
{

    Hashtable<String,Object> env = new Hashtable<>();

    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
        "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");

    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=XXXXXXX");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "YYYYYYY");

    try
    {
        /* Create initial context with no connection request controls */
        LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

        /* Sort Control is required for VLV to work */
        SortKey[] sortKeys =
        {
            // sort by cn 
            new SortKey("cn", true, "caseIgnoreOrderingMatch")
        };
        // Note: the constructors for SortControl that take String or String[]
        // as the first argument produce 'no ordering  rule' errors with OpenLDAP.
        SortControl sctl = new SortControl(
            // "cn",
            //  new String[]{"cn"},
            sortKeys,
            Control.CRITICAL);

        /* VLV that returns the first 20 answers */
        VirtualListViewControl vctl =
            new VirtualListViewControl(1, 0, 0, LIST_SIZE-1, Control.CRITICAL);

        /* Set context's request controls */
        ctx.setRequestControls(new Control[]
            {
                sctl,
                vctl
            });

        int count = 0;
        SearchControls  sc = new SearchControls(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE, 0, 0, null, false, false);
        for (;;)
        {
            /* Perform search */
//          System.out.println("namespace="+ctx.getNameInNamespace());
//          System.out.println("count limit="+sc.getCountLimit());
//          System.out.println("search scope="+sc.getSearchScope());
            NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> ne =
                ctx.search("ou=Users,dc=xxxx,dc=com", "(objectClass={0})", new String[]{"inetOrgPerson"}, sc);

            /* Enumerate search results */
            while (ne.hasMore())
            {
                count++;
                SearchResult sr = ne.next();
//              System.out.println(i+": "+sr.getName());
                System.out.println(count+": "+sr.getNameInNamespace());
            }

            ne.close();

            // Get the contextID.
            Control[] controls = ctx.getResponseControls();
            VirtualListViewResponseControl vlvrc = null;
            byte[] contextID = null;
            for (int j = 0; j < controls.length; j++)
            {
                if (controls[j] instanceof VirtualListViewResponseControl)
                {
                    vlvrc = (VirtualListViewResponseControl)controls[j];
                    contextID = vlvrc.getContextID();
                    System.out.println("contextID=0x"+new BigInteger(1,contextID).toString(16));
                    if (contextID != null)
                    {
                        vctl = new VirtualListViewControl(vlvrc.getTargetOffset()+LIST_SIZE, 0, 0, LIST_SIZE-1, Control.CRITICAL);
                        vctl.setContextID(contextID);
                        ctx.setRequestControls(new Control[]
                                        {
                                            sctl,
                                            vctl
                                        });
                    }
                    break;  // there should only be one VLV response control, and we're not interested in anything else.
                }
            }
            if (vlvrc != null && contextID != null && count < vlvrc.getListSize())
            {
                System.out.println("Continuing");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Finished");
                break;
            }
        }

        ctx.close();

    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
```

Adjust the authentication and search root and filter to suit yourself, of course.

And to test whether it is supported (although an 'unsupported critical control' exception from the above code will tell you just as well):

```
/**
 * Is VLV Control supported?
 *
 * Query the rootDSE object to find out if VLV Control is supported.
 * @return true if it is supported.
 */
static boolean isVLVControlSupported(LdapContext ctx)
    throws NamingException
{
    String[]    returningAttributes = 
    {
        "supportedControl"
    };

    // Fetch the supportedControl attribute of the rootDSE object.
    Attributes  attrs = ctx.getAttributes("", returningAttributes);
    Attribute   attr = attrs.get("supportedControl");
    System.out.println("supportedControls="+attr);
    if (attr != null)
    {
        // Fast way to check. add() would have been just as good. Does no damage to the DIT.
        return attr.remove(VLV_CONTROL_OID);
    }
    return false;
}
```

The `VirtualListViewControl` and `VirtualListViewResponseControl` are part of the Sun/Oracle LDAP Booster Pack, which you can obtain via Maven as:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>ldapbp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This is awesome. I ended up using a version of this from spring ldap. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/blob/master/sandbox/src/main/java/org/springframework/ldap/control/VirtualListViewControlDirContextProcessor.java

Comment: Well great, but your question says it is not officially supported, and you asked how to do it with the `javax` package, so I answered that.

Answer (score 1):

Super frustrating..

I wouldn't really recommend it, but you *could* pull off something like this where you manually paginate by cn/sn..

```
List<String> alphabetRange = getAlphabetRange();
for (int i = 0; i < alphabetRange.size() - 1; i++) {
    String filter = "(&(sn>=" + alphabetRange.get(i) + ")" + "(sn<=" + alphabetRange.get(i + 1) + " ))";
    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> searchResult = context.search(base_dn, filter, controls);
    while (searchResult.hasMore()) {
     // searchResult.next().getAttributes() and do something with it
    }
}
```

```
private List<String> getAlphabetRange() {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (char alph = 'A'; alph <= 'Z'; alph++) {
        if (alph == 'S') {
            result.add("S");
            result.add("Sd");
        } else {
            result.add(String.valueOf(alph));
        }
    }
    result.add("Zz");
    return result;
}
```

- as soon as you run over (i.e. 1.000) in one "page", you will face the dreaded `javax.naming.SizeLimitExceededException`. You might add more "pages", like in that example between `[S-Sd][Sd-T]`

Answer (score -1):

What exacly servers are you using?

if server has no queue limits you cant try set unlimited search:

```
SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
controls.setTimeLimit(0);
controls.setCountLimit(0);
```

Comment: Hard to see how an answer with no pagination at all answers a question about how to implement pagination.